# Limiting the number of posts in WP_Query leads to unexpected result

Tags: posts, wp-query, limit

The following is supposed to display 10 posts.

Sometimes it displays 11, sometimes 12, and sometimes the desired 10 posts. It behaves the same if I swap `posts_per_page` for `showposts` or `numberposts` .

Where do I need to search for the problem?

```
<ul>
    <? wp_reset_query(); ?> 
    <?  $args = array(
        'orderby'           => 'rand',
        'posts_per_page'    => '10',
    );
    $query_footerFavorite = new WP_Query($args);

    while ($query_footerFavorite->have_posts()) : $query_footerFavorite->the_post(); ?>

        <li>
            <a href="<? the_permalink(); ?>" title="<? the_title_attribute(); ?>">
                <? the_title(); ?>
            </a>
        </li>

    <? endwhile; ?>
    <? wp_reset_query(); ?>                 
</ul>
```

Edit: It seams there is a problem with the posts_per_page, see `print_r($query_footerFavorite)`:

```
WP_Query Object ( [query_vars] => Array ( [orderby] => rand [posts_per_page] => 10 [error]
```

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Pagination_Parameters

Comment: @mrwweb thank you, `'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1` solves the problem. One thing I don't understand though is that while `posts_per_page` returns the number of posts that I want, `numberposts` returns more than I want. So does `numberposts` automatically include the stickies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expected behavior of `posts_per_page` is to NOT count sticky posts. This can be resolved with `'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1`, but then the posts don't stick to the top of the menu. (In the [trac ticket for sticky posts](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/7457) this issue is discussed.)

There are some workarounds like [this one](http://wpengineer.com/293/strange-things-with-sticky-posts/), but they all feel a bit hacky to me. Personally I try to just deal with the expected behavior and make sure to style the `sticky` post class.

`showposts` is deprecated since WP2.1 and `numberposts` seems to only be a valid parameter for `get_posts()`. (Although I admittedly am unsure why. There's no mention of that issue on the Codex.)